# How to apply color palette number in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I want to use Material Design's Pink color palette. [CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCTnJ.png)

#880E4F or *pink[900]* works on this code

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I Am Rich'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

However, when I want to use #FF80E4F or *pink[A100]* it doesn't work at all?
It says

```
lib/main.dart:11:38: Error: Getter not found: 'A100'.
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[A100],
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Color(0xff880E4F)` should do the trick.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html

Edit:

Your example image seems to be outdated. Don't use `pink[A100]`. Use `Colors.pinkAccent[100]` Check the docs on how to correctly get the accent colors:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF80E4F),
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest you are passing incorrect values

Color function only accepts value between `[100] - [900]`

Try using **`Colors.pink[100]`**

If you want to color from hex code try by this method

```
Color(0xFFFF80E4F)
```

Also if you want to use color by changing opacity use can use this

```
Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.5)  // values between 0.0 - 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For hex code colors, you have to use (0xFF(Hex code))

Eg: For 880E4F, the corresponding color would be (0xFF880E4F)